# Why doesn't this proof of the Basel problem violate the geometric series convergence constraints?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

[In a proof of the Basel problem](https://youtu.be/5-pXwWNcsbc0), the excellent YouTuber "blackpenredpen" relies on a manipulation which I assume is valid, but I don't know why it is valid.

They split the following integral:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(2\cos x)\space dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})\space dx=$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(e^{ix}(1+e^{-2ix}))\space dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(e^{ix})\space dx + \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(1+e^{-2ix}))\space dx$$

And in the calculation of the second part of the integral on the right hand side, they use the series expansion:

$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$

to represent $\ln(1+e^{-2ix})$ and note that this is only valid for $|x|\leq1, x\neq-1$. Although $|e^{-2ix}|=1,\forall x$, I noticed that the integral runs up to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $e^{-2i\cdot\pi/2}=-1$, which means that the series expansion does not converge (the logarithm goes to $\ln(0)$ which is very undefined!) at the upper bound of the integral. I imagine this is valid due to integrals being limits, and perhaps we "approach" $\frac{\pi}{2}$ without reaching it, but I'd like a formal explanation for why this expansion is valid here - I would like to learn when we can and cannot do this sort of thing!

Comment: The remainder term in the Taylor series is relevant here.  The Taylor series to $n$ terms involves the first $n$ derivatives, then the remainder term involves the $n+1$th.  Then you try to show the remainder approaches zero.

Comment: The original integral is improper, since the integrand has a singularity at $x=\pi/2$. So the integral is defined to be $\lim_{t\nearrow \pi/2}\int_0^t \ln(2\cos x)\,dx$. (I'm assuming these are Riemann integrals, improper integrals are treated differently in e.g. Lebesgue integration) Separately, it might be a little risky to assume a manipulation is valid just because it arrives at the correct answer.

Comment: @JulianRosen Since we are approach $\pi/2$ in a limit, can this now be valid since the precise value of $\pi/2$ doesn't "quite" get reached so the series never "quite" diverges? I understand continuity well enough to understand that I'm being very hand-wavy here

Comment: this logic is flawed: "relies on a manipulation which is clearly valid, since their proof produces the correct answer"

Comment: Arriving at the right answer does not mean that one's technique is valid. For example, in $16/64,$ if one cancels the $6$ from the numerator and the denominator, one gets $1/4.$ And it is correct that $16/64$ reduced to lowest terms is $1/4. \qquad$

Comment: @mathworker21 I understand your points, which have also already been raised - I simply meant that I trusted the youtuber, prestigious as he is with a following close to a million, to have not made a mistake here, and I believed in his results. I will remove the comment “clearly it is valid” to avoid confusion

Comment: Seems like a job for dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: That guy has a video that is incorrect and down right stupid and nonsensical, and have made no attempt to correct it , wouldn't take their work as gospel .

Comment: @jimjim which video?

Comment: @IdioticShrike : This one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ExXldVjYp8  , any bozo with high school level of complex numbers can do it the result is wrong and it is still left up there, choose your idols carefully

Comment: @jimjim What is the answer supposed to be? I don't idolise him, I just have learned a fair few things from him. Is $0^i$ actually defined ? I check around on other sources and they seemed to concur with bprp that is is undefined

Comment: @IdioticShrike : what other sources? why wouldn't it be defined? writing in polar form it is trivial to calculate it. Seriously ? people can not calculate and decide for themselves anymore? as one of the comments says using the same flawed logic as the video then $0^1, 0^2, \cdot, 0^k $ is also not defined which is rubbish, secondly not only it has a value, it has many values, to see that observe with $1^i,(\frac{1}{2})^i,(\frac{1}{3})^i,,(\frac{1}{4})^i,\cdots,,(\frac{1}{n})^i$ all have values,  at  0 there will be many values.

Comment: @jimjim Wolfram Alpha would seem to disagree with you and labels it as undefined. The polar form argument hasn’t led me anywhere: $0^i=(re^{i\theta})^i=(r^i)(e^{-\theta})=0^i\cdot e^{-\theta}$ where $\theta$ could be anything and we are still left with $0^i$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $\epsilon>0$, we wish to evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}\ln(1+e^{-2ix})dx$. Let $\delta>0$ be small, so that

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}\ln(1+e^{-2ix})dx=\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}\ln(1+(1-\delta)e^{-2ix})dx+\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{-2ix}}{1+(1-\delta)e^{-2ix}}\right)dx.
\end{align}
Here,
\begin{align}
\left|\ln\left(\frac{1+e^{-2ix}}{1+(1-\delta)e^{-2ix}}\right)\right|&=\left|\ln\left(1-\frac\delta{1+e^{2ix}}\right)\right|\\
&\le\frac32\frac\delta{|1+e^{2ix}|}\\
&=\frac32\frac\delta{\sqrt{(1+\cos(2x))^2+\sin^2(2x)}}\\
&=\frac32\frac\delta{\sqrt{2+2\cos(2x)}},\\
\end{align}
(here, I used [this bound](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bounds_for_Complex_Logarithm)), so for $\delta$ small enough, the second term disappears, since $2+2\cos x\ge 2-2\cos(2\epsilon)>0$. Now, one can safely trade the limit and the integral [because of uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_integrability):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}\ln(1+(1-\delta)e^{-2ix})dx&=\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^{n-1}\frac1n(1-\delta)^ne^{-2nix}dx\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^{n-1}\frac1n(1-\delta)^n\int_0^{\pi/2-\epsilon}e^{-2nix}dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac1{2n^2i}(1-\delta)^n(1-(-1)^ne^{2ni\epsilon}).
\end{align}
Since $\epsilon,\delta>0$ were arbitrary, we can take the limit as they approach $0$.

Comment: Very thorough thank you,... is the takeaway for me that in any improper integral, I must manually check if the limits exist as we closer to the improper bound? There is no intuitive or good rule as such to determine the validity of such an integral?

Comment: Also, your placement of $\delta$ in the original integral didn’t affect the integral at all, so I’m not sure what purpose $\delta$ has; surely one could just take the limit as $\epsilon$ approaches zero... as delta varies the integral expression never varied, is what I mean to say

Comment: The point of $\delta$ was to be able to exchange the limit and the integral. Uniform convergence requires the terms in the series to decrease quickly, and $\frac1ne^{-2nix}$ doesn't (but $\frac1n(1-\delta)^ne^{-2nix}$ does).

Comment: Do you happen to know the name or origin of the statement you linked on the Wikipedia page? It seems a very useful result, and I'd like to see a proof (but as usual Wikipedia just states the fact without showing where it came from)

Comment: @IdioticShrike it is an easy exercise in $\epsilon-\delta$.